# Fixed button bar Instagram style - android app

Tags: android, button, android-actionbar, android-applicationinfo

I am trying to code a fixed button bar at the bottom of the page like it may be found on Instagram at the bottom of the screen.

Screenshot:

[image]

[More similar images](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=instagram+screenshot&hl=en&tbm=isch&imgil=2MTnv5Z4ZojOiM%253A%253BiCZP8EwjvVE3pM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.digitalspy.com%25252Ftech%25252Fi403328-8%25252Finstagram-for-android-screenshots-instagram-for-android-screenshot-feed.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=2MTnv5Z4ZojOiM%253A%252CiCZP8EwjvVE3pM%252C_&usg=__G_DibJslemEQoRLdywm-WT-Ydr0%3D&biw=1366&bih=622&ved=0CDQQyjc&ei=yRDZVOiFO6KL7Aa98IGoCA#hl=en&tbm=isch&q=instagram+screenshot&imgdii=_)

The buttons at the bottom of the page are fixed there. I tried to put a new relative layout with a background colour with 5 image buttons, but when I change the screen size some buttons disappears. 
I tried a split action bar, but it is not what I am after.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: My answer should give you approximately what you need. But, in the future, consider posting your attempt so we can help guide you and know what you have already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each button to take up the same amount of space then just use a `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`. You can then use the `layout_weight` param for each. Roughly...

```
<LinearLayout
    ...>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        .../>
    <ImageButton
        // just like above />
</LinearLayout>
```